# HikariPool shutdown in every interval and restarts after sometime

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

In my application logs I can see that Hikaripool shutting down in every interval of time, lets say 30 or 45 minutes and restarts after few minutes. During that time application is showing bad gateway.

ERROR :

Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
HikariPool-1 - Before shutdown stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc................ (connection evicted)
HikariPool-1 - After shutdown stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
after this Application restarted.

Pool size is 20 ,so we Changed min idle to 20. But no progress.

"org.springframework.boot" version "2.6.5"

Comment: can you https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you. It was some issue with health endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
After some library updates health check URLs changed, we were using swagger url for that. So after every 2 hrs when it is doing a health check it failed, because old swagger endpoints were not available, which is causing the application to shutdown and restart.